# glTexImage2DMultisample with un-normalized texture-formats

Tags: opengl, glsl, opengl-3, multisampling

I am having difficulty with rendering multisampled textures with un-normalized internal formats such as `GL_RGBA32UI`, `GL_RGBA32I`.
Here is my code:

```
width1=height1=32;
*target11=GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE,*format=GL_RGBA16UI;
*samples=1;
glGenTextures(1, &id1);
glBindTexture(*target11, id1);
glGenFramebuffers(1, &Fboid);
GLint framebuffer;
glGetIntegerv(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER_BINDING,&framebuffer);
glGenRenderbuffers(1, &depth);
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT,1);
glTexImage2DMultisample(GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE, *samples ,*format, width1, height1,true);    
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, Fboid);

glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, depth);
glRenderbufferStorageMultisample(GL_RENDERBUFFER,*samples, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24, width1, height1);
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, depth);            glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER,GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,*target11,id1,0);
glEnable(GL_MULTISAMPLE);
draw_cube(0);

glDisable(GL_MULTISAMPLE);  
status = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER);
switch(status)
    {
            case GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE:                       tdkPrintf("GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE\n");                        break;
            case 0x8CDB:                                        tdkPrintf("GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_DRAW_BUFFER\n");          break;
            case GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT:          tdkPrintf("GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT\n");           break;
            case GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_MISSING_ATTACHMENT:  tdkPrintf("GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_MISSING_ATTACHMENT\n");   break;        
            case GL_FRAMEBUFFER_UNSUPPORTED:                    tdkPrintf("GL_FRAMEBUFFER_UNSUPPORTED\n");                     break;  
            default:                                            tdkPrintf("Unknown issue (%X).\n",status);                     break;
        }

glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer);

render_cube();
```

To normalizizing the texture data in fragment shader manually:
for `GL_RGBA16UI`: `factor = 65535`

```
uniform usampler2DMS tk_diffuseMap;
in vec3 ps_texCoord;
out vec4 fragColor;
uniform int samples;
uniform uint factor; 
void main(void)
{

    vec2 iTmp = textureSize(tk_diffuseMap);
    vec2 tmp =floor(iTmp * ps_texCoord.xy);
    uvec3 temp;  
    vec3 temp1;
    vec4 color;
    for(int i = 0; i < samples; ++i)
    {
         temp= texelFetch(tk_diffuseMap, ivec2(tmp), i).rgb;
         temp1=vec3(temp);
         temp1=temp1/factor;
        color = color + vec4(temp1,1.0);
    }

    fragColor = vec4(color/samples);
}
```

With this code i am getting white texture to whole geometry. However, it works fine with normalized texture formats.
What is correct way of writing to frame-buffer in case of un-normalized textures?

Comment: `GLenum *target11=GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE,*format=GL_RGBA16UI;` How are these not generating compile errors? You have some extraneous `*`s in there. Also, it's not clear what you're actually writing to your multisample buffer. Specifically what you're writing, like the exact numbers and so forth. Because if you're writing the same stuff as you would to normalized formats, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: @NicolBolas:  am rendering a cube of white color on Fboid which is same in both normaliezed and un-normalized textures.

Comment: @NicolBolas Can you tell me the correct way of doing it?

Comment: "*am rendering a cube of white color on Fboid which is same in both normaliezed and un-normalized textures.*" You can't be rendering it the same way in both and expect to get the same answer. There's a reason why integer textures are separate from normalized ones; you put different values into them and get different ones out.

Comment: @Roshan: You need to seriously polish up your C/C++ knowledge, at least when it comes to pointers and pointer syntax.

Comment: @datenwolf: Actually it was declared in the starting phase of my program. Just wanted to put a data type while adding code here, hence it was a mistake here. Now, i corrected it. :)

Comment: @datenwolf: can you guys tell me the correct way of writing a buffer for un-normalized textures